# Visual Studio , matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix-multiplication

Well here is my code, not finished, but I'm getting 2 issues I don't know how to fix.

First because most of the people here and English speakers
`nCA/B/C-number os colums A/B/C      nLA/B/C-number os lines A/B/C&#96;&#96;`
My problems are , the fact that the following program , doesnt properly multiply and make the correct size , even though i defined `nLC = nLA ; nCC = nCB` , Matrix A always come before the B one , its still not complete the program , but I can't figure this problems out

I know the composition is bad , but its how we are supposed to built it , with this kind of memory allocations.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char menu;
    int i, j;
    int n_linhas, n_colunas; int nLA, nCA, nLB, nCB, nLC, nCC;
    int **Matriz_A, **Matriz_B, **Matriz_C;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("C:\\PC\\FicheiroEscrito.txt", "w+");
    printf("\n Qual a dimensao da matriz A?\n");
    scanf_s(" %d%d", &nLA,&nCA);
    printf("\n Qual a dimensao da matriz B?\n");
    scanf_s(" %d%d", &nLB,&nCB);
    nLC = nLA ;
    nCC = nCB ;
    char option;

    if (nCA!=nLB)
   {        
        printf("\Dimensoes nao multiplicaveis");
        printf("\n\n\n");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
   }

   do {
       //File  , text , exit
       printf("\n Bem vindos a um programa \n");
       printf("\n Que pretende calcular a multiplicação de duas matrizes A e B\n");
       printf("\n sendo este um programa que foi construido atraves dos conhecimentos adquiridos durante o semestre\n");
       printf("\n Como este demonstra , arrays , allocacoes de memoria e funcoes \n");
       printf("\n Como quer fornecer os dados ao programa? \n");
       printf("\n Por Teclado        (responda*T*)\n");
       printf("\n Por Ficheiro       (responda*F*)\n");
       printf("\n Desejo sair        (responda*S*)\n");
       scanf(" %c", &option);
       fprintf(file, "\n Menu principal\n");
       fprintf(file, "\n Como quer fornecer os dados ao programa? \n");
       fprintf(file, "\n Por Teclado    (responda*T*) \n");
       fprintf(file, "\n Por Ficheiro   (responda*F*)\n");
       fprintf(file, "\n Desejo sair    (responda*S*)\n");
       fprintf(file, "\n %c \n", option);

       switch (option)
       {
         case 'S':
         case 's':
             exit(1);
             break;

         case 'T': // por teclado
         case't':
        Matriz_A = (int**)malloc(nLA*sizeof(int*));
        for (i = 0; i < nLA; i++)
        {
            Matriz_A[i] = (int*)malloc(nCA*sizeof(int));
        }
        if (Matriz_A == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n A alocacao de memoria para a matriz nao foi feita\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        Matriz_B = (int**)malloc(nLB*sizeof(int*));
        for (i = 0; i < nLB; i++)
        {
            Matriz_B[i] = (int*)malloc(nCB*sizeof(int));
        }
        if (Matriz_B == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n A alocacao de memoria para a matriz nao foi feita\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        Matriz_C = (int**)malloc(nLC*sizeof(int*));
        for (i = 0; i < nLC; i++)
        {
            Matriz_C[i] = (int*)malloc(nCC*sizeof(int));
        }
        if (Matriz_C == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n A alocacao de memoria para a matriz nao foi feita\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < nLA; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < nCA; j++)
            {
                printf("\n Qual o valor do elemento da matriz A [%d] [%d]?\n", i, j);
                scanf_s(" %d", &Matriz_A[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < nLB; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < nCB; j++)
            {
                printf("\n Qual o valor do elemento da matriz B [%d] [%d]?\n", i, j);
                scanf_s(" %d", &Matriz_B[i][j]);
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < nLA; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < nCB; j++)
            {
                Matriz_C[i][j] += Matriz_A[i][j] * Matriz_B[i][j];
            }
        }
        printf("\n  DADOS  \n");
        printf("\nMatriz A \n");
        for (i = 0; i < nLA; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < nCA; j++)
            {
                printf("%4d  ", Matriz_A[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
            printf("\nMatriz B \n");
            for (i = 0; i < nLB; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < nCB; j++)
                {
                    printf("%4d   ", Matriz_B[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("\n  RESULTADOS  \n");
            printf("\nMatriz C \n");
            for (i = 0; i < nLC; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < nCA; j++)
                {
                    printf("%4d  ", Matriz_C[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            for (i = 0; i < nLC; i++)
            {
                free(Matriz_C[i]);
            }
            free(Matriz_C);
            for (i = 0; i < nLB; i++)
            {
                free(Matriz_B[i]);
            }
            free(Matriz_B);

        for (i = 0; i < nLA; i++)
            {
                free(Matriz_A[i]);
            }
            free(Matriz_A);


            while (option != 'T');
            printf("\n\n\n");
            fprintf(file, "\n\n\n");
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    while (option != 'S');
    printf("\n\n\n");
    printf ("\n\n\n");
    system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question for readability. Prose and code. I tried but you lost me at "people here and english speakears nCA/B/C-number".

Comment: the formating lost some words my bad .
i wanted to say , for most people here and english speakers , then i had the translation , because i wrote thee int variables with native words , so to say

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below your question to edit it and improve the readability. You are aware that "the formatting lost some words", please fix that. Using a newline often helps with readability. You can use the "backward ticks" to make `code quotes`, which also keep most other special characters exactly as you type them. Even with your explanation I still do not get what you mean around the "English speakers". Clarify that and the "os" things - then somebody will help with the rest. You can find help on formatting in the help center, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting